# Bind9 - local configuration is it important

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I have a dedicated server and i have DNS and web server on the same server. To configure the DNS i have used `BIND` ... BIND comes with default configuration for localhost like `127, 0 , 255 and localhost`. I have removed the `type:hint` part that is used for caching.

my doubt is that

1. do i really require these configuration as my DNS is `Authorative Only` and if i require these config are they Authrorative only or are they Caching Server
2. If i require these config file then are they only used internally or can they be used from outsiders

Here ar my conf file as requested:

named.conf.options:

```
options {
    directory "/etc/bind";
    version "Hello";
    recursion no;
    allow-transfer{none;};
    managed-keys-directory "/etc/bind";
    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //      0.0.0.0;
    // };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

named.conf.default-zones

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/master/master.example.com";
};

zone "X.X.X.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/master/master.X.X.X.X";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

My named.conf.local is blank so i have not added it
and the zone files are normal and working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default bind configuration enables a large number of [built-in empty zones](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#empty) when recursion is enabled. This is done without manually defining any zones, i.e. the zones that you previously had defined in your config file are probably entirely redundant.

The root hint zone ([`type hint` zone](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2594726) for `.`) is only needed for recursion, but that also has a built-in default and would work without manually specifying it in your config file.

What you do want to make sure for an authoritative-only server is that you either disable recursion entirely or limit recursion access. See the [`recursion`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#boolean_options) and [`allow-recursion`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) options (as well as the other [`allow-*`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) options, which do interact to some degree when you start overriding some of them).

Comment: i have added the conf file

Comment: @AnkitLadhania I don't think my answer requires any changes based on that. Ie, you have disabled recursion (`recursion no`) which is the essential thing to achieve an authoritative-only server. The manually defined empty zones do not really serve a purpose for an authoritative-only server but even if it was not an authoritative-only server (ie, if you allowed recursion from some set of hosts) only the `localhost` zone out of all those actually adds anything compared to what bind already includes by default.

Comment: so i can remove all the empty zone then and it wont cause any problem

Comment: Yes, no one is expected to query your authoritative-only server for `localhost`, etc. since there are no delegations to you for those zones. And even if someone were to send such queries your server will just respond that it can't answer.  The reason why these empty zones are relevant on servers with recursion enabled is that otherwise such queries are passed on to the root servers.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post your config information for us to be able to answer this.  An authorative only server does not requite default configurations for localhost etc, only the zones it is authorative for.

Comment: I Have Added the conf file